# What kind of datetime object is this? Could not convert with new Date()

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, facebook-graph-api, iso

I am receiving post data from Facebook Graph API and the posts have an "updated_at" attribute with a string value like this:

`469164-11-24T23:43:20+0000`

Whats odd is that the FB graph explorer returns a "created_at" attribute with a datetime object like this: (Not the equivalent date, just showing the format)

`2016-09-12T22:53:59+0000`

I have no idea what is going on. The first weird date cannot convert to an ISO date object with new Date(). I have checked previous version of the Graph API and they also return a normal ISO date object. I am really confused, but my app is in production so I need solve this issue.. truely stumped. Does anyone recognize this and know a way to convert it into a standard ISO date?

Comment: The first "object" is a string. It is not a valid ISO 8601 date string so the result is implementation dependent (most likely an invalid date). There is no  ECMAScript "ISO date object", there are ISO 8601 format strings.

Comment: @RobG any clue on how to convert this string to a valid date? The string  MM-DD digits `469164-11-24T23:43:20+0000` do not correspond to Nov 24th 2016 I am certain.

Comment: The only way to interpret 469164-11-24T23:43:20+0000 is as a non–ISO 8601 date string, so parsing is implementation dependent. In any case, it should return "Invalid Date" since even if the year is treated as 469164, the limit is about ±285,426 years from 1970 so out of range. So I have no idea how 469164-11-24 should be treated.

Comment: I see, ok thank you!